# Regarding UK visitor visa application

Tags: visas, uk

My UK visitor visa interview is on 18 January and i am planning to visit in June, 2018. I saw a PDF stating i cannot apply 3 months before my intended date to visit UK. Will they refuse my application?

Comment: Which PDF was that?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot apply earlier than three months before you travel. See [Standard Visitor Visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa) on the UK government web site. Scroll down to "How long will it take?"

I don't know whether you'll be refused, or if they'll just return your application to you with a note asking to to apply later. If you've already applied I guess you'll find out soon enough.

Comment: true that. I can extend my appointment until 23rd Feb which will be 3 months and 6 days before my intended date to visit UK. Should i change my appointment to 23rd feb or i should just go on 18 Jan?